# npm install angular cli failling with 502 error on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm trying to install the latest angular cli with npm:

```
sudo -s npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

But I'm always getting 502 error:

```
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/smilhais/package.json'
npm WARN smilhais No description
npm WARN smilhais No repository field.
npm WARN smilhais No README data
npm WARN smilhais No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lodash.assign@4.2.0 (node_modules/lodash.assign):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: lodash.assign@https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.assign/-/lodash.assign-4.2.0.tgz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: loader-runner@2.3.0 (node_modules/loader-runner):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: loader-runner@https://registry.npmjs.org/loader-runner/-/loader-runner-2.3.0.tgz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: clone@2.1.1 (node_modules/less-loader/node_modules/clone):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: clone@https://registry.npmjs.org/clone/-/clone-2.1.1.tgz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lazy-cache@0.2.7 (node_modules/lazy-cache):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: lazy-cache@https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy-cache/-/lazy-cache-0.2.7.tgz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: har-validator@4.2.1 (node_modules/har-validator):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: har-validator@https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator/-/har-validator-4.2.1.tgz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: jsonify@0.0.0 (node_modules/jsonify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: jsonify@https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonify/-/jsonify-0.0.0.tgz
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: is-number@2.1.0 (node_modules/is-number):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 502 Connection timed out: is-number@https://registry.npmjs.org/is-number/-/is-number-2.1.0.tgz

npm ERR! code E502
npm ERR! 502 Connection timed out: lodash.clonedeep@https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.clonedeep/-/lodash.clonedeep-4.5.0.tgz
```

Does anybody know why do I get this? And how to fix it?

Versions:
Node v8.0.0 -- npm  5.0.3 -- npm  Registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Linux: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/smilhais/package.json'` - Did you do an **npm init** before **npm install**?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @KonstantinA.Magg. I did not execute npm init before npm install. My problem was that I had a proxy. I disabled it and it worked fine.